# Advice on interactions between service, activity, and notifications

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am implementing a Service which will start when MainActivity starts. This service checks for and maintains a network connection.

I have not bound the Service to the Activity because I want the service to continue running even if the activity isn't available. The Service will receive messages from the server that it is connected to.

I am struggling to choose the best logic to do the following when the service receives a message.

Check if MainActivity is currently open and in front of the user

If it is call some methods in the activity to interact with the UI

If there is no activity update the notification are.

My question is;

How do I correctly check if the activity is running in the UI from my service? I know that I could bind the service but I wouldn't want to unbind it if the activity is closed. Would that be a problem?

I will somehow need to send messages from the service to the activity. Given the above scenario what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it differently.

- If your Service does not run in a separate process from your Activities, then your Service can provide a synchronized (multithread-safe) list of messages via a subcalssed `Application` object, where your Activity can look it up. However, this would only be best if the polling occurs on certain other events.
- If you want to sort of "push" the message to your Activity, your Activity should register with your service upon finding out that it runs, not the other way round. In this scenario, your Activity should implement an interface through which the Service can notify your Activity of new messages in a Thread-safe way.

Of course you could also go straightforward and simply post notifications which open an Activity, but as I understood it, you want to provide a more smooth integration.

Comment: Class,This seems like a good approach, especially your second point. However it appears that I would still need a reference to the activity in the service (in order to call the interface method). Could you give me a clue as to how I would get one and how I would check the the activity is open?

Comment: @Stephen Both your Service and your Activity/ies can access your subclassed Application object via `Activity.getApplication()` and `Service.getApplication(). You typecast the result. Then, your Service "registers" with the Application object (/stores a reference to itself. The Application object then offers methods for Activities to tell the Service they're there or gone. I'd call these in `onResume()` and `onPause()` for safety reasons (aka NullPointer avoidance). Then, your Service can reach your app's active Activity. This at the same time guarantees that your Activity is currently on top.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to let your Service send status bar notifications when a new update is available.
Implement the notification such that when clicked, to open `MainActivity`.

Then, when the user will click on the notification, if the `MainActivity` is already running then it will be brought to front, otherwise it will be started.
So this basically eliminates the need to check if `MainActivity` is currently open in front of the user (which I see as a bad practice).

Comment: Hey Andy,Thanks for your response. This is a sensible approach however it doesn't fit into how the application works.